# SQLite create dynamic table (or view?)

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, pivot

I have 3 tables:

Table.Keys, Table.Tags, Table.Values

Table.Keys create table statement:

```
    createTableStatement = "CREATE TABLE " + Tables.KEYS + "("
            + KeysColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KeysColumns.KEY + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + "UNIQUE ("
            + KeysColumns.KEY
            + ") ON CONFLICT IGNORE"
            + ");";
    execSQL(sqLiteDatabase, createTableStatement);
```

Table.Tags create table statement:

```
    createTableStatement = "CREATE TABLE " + Tables.TAGS + " ("
            + TagsColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + TagsColumns.NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + "UNIQUE ("
            + TagsColumns.NAME
            + ") ON CONFLICT IGNORE"
            + ");";
    execSQL(sqLiteDatabase, createTableStatement);
```

Table.Value create table statement:

```
    createTableStatement = "CREATE TABLE " + Tables.VALUES + " ("
            + ValuesColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + ValuesColumns.KEY_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + ValuesColumns.TAG_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + ValuesColumns.VALUE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + "UNIQUE ("
            + ValuesColumns.KEY_ID + ", " + ValuesColumns.TAG_ID
            + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE"
            + ");";
    execSQL(sqLiteDatabase, createTableStatement);
```

If I do the following join:

```
Tables.KEYS
+ " JOIN " + Tables.VALUES
+ " ON " + Values.KEY_ID + " = " + Keys.column(Keys._ID)
+ " JOIN " + Tables.TAGS
+ " ON " + Values.TAG_ID + " = " + Tags.column(Tags._ID);
```

I get duplicate rows of course because the result is

```
KEY | TAG | VALUE
=================
    |     |
```

What I would like to accomplish is to query and get a Cursor from table or view with no duplicate rows with the following schema:

```
KEY | TAG 1 | TAG 2 | ... | TAG n
=================================
    |       |       |     |
```

Not all keys *MUST* have values for each tag, but all keys *CAN* have values.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this. I'm not even sure where to start.

In the meantime I have created another table which stores some TAG values that I know will always exist.

But I feel this is inefficient because at any time I could have 'n' number of new TAG values which is why I would like to be able to create a view or table with the schema I listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has no pivot functions; you have to do this in two steps.

First, get all possible tags:

```sql
SELECT _id, Name
FROM Tags
ORDER BY Name;
```

Then, using the returned data, construct a query that looks up each possible tag for each key:

```sql
SELECT Key,
       (SELECT Value
        FROM Values
        WHERE Key_ID = Keys._id
          AND Tag_ID = 111
       ) AS Tag_111,
       (SELECT Value
        FROM Values
        WHERE Key_ID = Keys._id
          AND Tag_ID = 222
       ) AS Tag_222,
       ...
FROM Keys;
```

Comment: so basically for loop the inner selects? (I'll test tomorrow and update)